# grunt-contrib-connect error :middleware undefined

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using yeoman's angular generator for my AngularJS app. This generator includes grunt and grunt-contrib-connect, which are very useful... but the dependencies are outdated, so I decided to update those.

When doing so, I have an error for grunt-contrib-connect, here it is when I use the --verbose option:

```
Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Verifying property connect.test exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: protocol="http", port=9001, hostname="localhost", base=".", directory=null, 
keepalive=false, debug=false, livereload=35729, open=false, useAvailablePort=false, 
onCreateServer=null, middleware=undefined
Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

So it seems that the middleware is responsible for this issue, here it is:

```
middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
```

Any assistance to help me figuring this out is more than welcome :)

Comment: I have the same problem, unsolved so far. FWIW, I don't think `middleware=undefined` is the problem, though, because I see the same in a project where grunt connect works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grunt-contrib-connect` version 0.10.1 seemed to solve this issue for me. [Issue 161](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/issues/161) may be related.